# Do predictions using training data

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

I have 2 csv files. one is a training dataset and the other is test dataset. Training dataset contains 36 columns. One column of that is the outcome which have A-F as values. The test dataset has 35 columns which does not have the outcome. I want to add an outcome column to the test dataset as well. I searched for several tutorials but did not find the method that I should follow. Can any one tell about the process that I should follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't supplied any sample data and the technique you want to use, my below code will have you to understand how can you make prediction in general:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```

Assuming you have read 2 csv files, `train` & `test`

```
X_train = train.loc[:, train.columns != 'Outcome'] # <---- Here you exclude the Outcome from train
y_train = train['Outcome'] # <---- This is your Outcome 

le = LabelEncoder()
y_train = le.fit_transform(y_train) # <---- Here you convert your A-F values to numeric(0-5)
```

I am assuming rest of the `x` variables are numeric.

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier() # <---- Here you call the classifier
rf.fit(X_train, y_train) # <---- Fit the classifier on train data
rf.score(X_train, y_train) # <---- Check model accuracy
y_pred = pd.DataFrame(rf.predict(test), columns = ['Outcome']) # <---- Make predictions on test data
test_pred = pd.concat([test, y_pred['Outcome']], axis = 1) # <---- Here you add predictions column to your test dataset
test_pred.to_excel(r'path\Test.xlsx')
```

Comment: It is working and I understand the concept now. Do you have any idea about writing it(test_pred) to an excel?

Comment: Edited my answer, replace 'path' with the folder path where you want to save the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you will find/calculate the outcome you need to add.

One way would be to load the test dataset as a Pandas data frame. Calculate the outcome and add the values to a list which you the add to your Pandas dataframe:

```python
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Names', 'Age', 'Outcome'])

names = ['John', 'Nicole', 'Evan']
age = [53, 23, 27]

data['Names'] = names
data['Age'] = age

outcome = [6545, 5252, 85665]

data['Outcome'] = outcome
```